# cannot send yahoo email using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, email

I'm working with a program that can send email supporting yahoo mail and gmail. And it works in gmail(if the sender utilizes gmail) But it won't work if the sender is using yahoo mail.
Here is my code:

```
    mail.From = New MailAddress(TextBox2.Text)
    mail.To.Add(New MailAddress(TextBox1.Text))
    mail.Subject = TextBox4.Text
    mail.Body = TextBox4.Text



    mail.IsBodyHtml = True

    Dim client2 As SmtpClient = New SmtpClient("smtp.mail.yahoo.com", 25)
    Dim client As SmtpClient = New SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587)




    client.EnableSsl = True
    client.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential(TextBox2.Text, TextBox3.Text)


    Try
        client.Send(mail)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Sending email failed. Please Try again")
```

Comment: It would be interesting to know the details of the exception.

Comment: A first chance exception of type 'System.Net.Mail.SmtpException' occurred in System.dll
The program '[2660] rewmail.vshost.exe: Managed' has exited with code 0 (0x0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you might be using the [wrong port](http://help.yahoo.com/l/us/yahoo/mail/original/mailplus/pop/pop-14.html)? Try this

```
Dim client2 As SmtpClient = New SmtpClient("smtp.mail.yahoo.com", 587)
```

---

**EDIT** 
OK, that didn't work. Actually, isn't the SMTP address also wrong?

```
Dim client2 As SmtpClient = New SmtpClient("plus.smtp.mail.yahoo.com", 587)
```

You could also wrap the whole program in a `Try` block and catch any [`SmtpException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpexception.aspx) and write out the special [SmtpStatusCode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpstatuscode.aspx):

```
Try 
  ' Blah blah '
Catch (SmtpException e)
   Console.WriteLine("Error: {0} {1}", e.StatusCode, e.ToString) 
End Try
```

Answer (score 0):

Yahoo uses Port 465 for non-paying users (subscription services).